# Finding the target of mouse events

Tags: java, gwt, mouseevent

I am new to GWT and am trying to get started using mouse events.

I have an AbsolutePanel which recieves MouseDown Events:

```
public class TestPanel extends AbsolutePanel implements MouseDownHandler,
        HasMouseDownHandlers {
    private Button a = new Button();
    private Button b = new Button();

    public TestPanel() {
        add(b);
        add(a);

        b.setStyleName("blue");

        setWidgetPosition(a, 200, 00);
        setWidgetPosition(b, 100, 50);


        setWidth("500px");
        setHeight("500px");

        addMouseDownHandler(this);
    }

    /**
     * MouseDownHandler
     */
    public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {

        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());

        System.out.println(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().equals(b.getElement()));
    }

    /**
     * HasMouseDownHandlers - Code to add handlers to the panel
     */
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseDownHandler(MouseDownHandler handler) {
        return addDomHandler(handler, MouseDownEvent.getType());
    }
}
```

What I have written so far seems to let me check which child of the AbsolutePanel has been clicked. What I would like to do is check if the target is an instance of a certain class, or if it implements a certain interface. Is there any way to do this? Is there an alternative method to what I am doing here that is preferred?

thanks,
Chris

Comment: Why don't you register mouse down handler to your widget(or as you call it target)? Just use `widget.addMouseDownHandler(...)`. Or in your case `a.addMouseDownHandler(...)` and `b.addMouseDownHandler(...)`.

Comment: I considered that, but I am potentially dealing with hundreds of objects. Is that approach scalable? I posted this question here because I was absolutely shocked that I needed to go to the native event to get the event target- this made me think I was making some fundamental mistake.

Comment: What do you mean scalable ? If you mean speed look at Google Docs. All of them use mouse events (addMouseDownHandler, MouseOverHandler...) and they are fast.